# ALAsset pointer throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS when access it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am developing an image gallery which permits to select some pictures from the iPhone and display them.

Some explanations about this gallery:

- An `UITableView` displays the different directories which contain iPhone pictures
- When the user click on one of these directories: Display an `UICollectionView` with the different pictures from the selected directory
- Back button to come back to the `UITableView`
- Next button to display the selected images in a new page.

How this gallery is implemented:

- For each directories found in iPhone pictures, store the `ALAssetsGroup` in an `NSMutableArray` named directoriesData
- Display the directories stored in directoriesData in an `UITableView`.
- When the user select one directory : Store each of the `ALAsset` contained in this directory in an `NSMutableArray` named picturesData.
- Display thumbnails in an `UICollectionView` from picturesData.
- When the user select a picture, it is stored in a singleton instance of `NSMutableArray` named desiredPictures.
- If the user click on the back button, I remove all the objects from the picturesData before display the `UITableView`.

Now the problem:

I have two different directories of pictures in my iPhone.

Directory A
Directory B

I want to select one picture in Directory A and one other in Directory B.

After select them, I click to the next page to display them.

The new page loads the images from the desiredPictures. 
But when I want display the selected pictures by accessing to the `ALAsset` of the Directory A, I have an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

After some test and research in my project, I found that if I do not remove the objects from picturesData (when I press button back), I don't have anymore the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

But, I need to clean the contents of picturesData because when I fill my `UICollectionView` it's from the picturesData. And in the case of I access to the directory A and then to directory B, I will have the content of the two directories in the `UICollectionView`.

So how can I keep `ALAsset` pointer correct and clean pictureData?

I hope you understand my project and problem.

Thanks !

[image: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/581536photo.jpg]

Edit:

Backtrace

*** thread #29: tid = 0x599a6, 0x39764b26 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6, queue = 'com.apple.root.high-priority, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)

    frame #0: 0x39764b26 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 6

    frame #1: 0x00195f1a MyProject`-[Picture getFullImage](self=0x176ebb40, _cmd=0x005de393) + 310 at Picture.m:211

    frame #2: 0x001959bc MyProject`-[Picture getCroppedImage](self=0x176ebb40, _cmd=0x005da2b4) + 68 at Picture.m:154

    frame #3: 0x001f9a82 MyProject`__68-[ImageCropViewController  sliderContentsAddContent:ToSlider:AtPage:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=0x17637000) + 50 at ImageCropViewController.m:1020

    frame #4: 0x39c4cd1a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10

    frame #5: 0x39c53d70 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 220

    frame #6: 0x39c53f58 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56

    frame #7: 0x39d8edbe libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 298**

Comment: What? you are storing all the images in NSMutableArray?

Comment: When a user select a directory in the first page, I store all the ALAsset (image) of the selected directory in a NSMutableArray. And I use this NSMutableArray to fill an UICollectionView.

Comment: Show the exception message and full stack trace.

Comment: First of all you should not store the images in an array you are doing it wrong. Bcz later it will create the memory pressure.

Comment: I just add the backtrace on my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has provided a clean way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Here is the sample code : [MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

and try to analyze the code and see what they are doing.!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In MyImagePicker, developers use NSMutableArray too to store the directories and pictures for a desired directories. I do the same thing in my project.

Comment: But you should store only the Asset url not the whole image. Otherwise you will get memory warning soon.!!

Comment: When you speak about "Asset url", you speak about the whole ALAsset object or myALAssetObject.defaultRepresentation.url ?

Comment: I mean the whole ALAsset object.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am storing. Not the image of course.